# Angular | Run event on other button

Tags: html, angular, typescript, event-handling

(Invalid question. You do not need to refer to it. Thank you.)

Solution : Use a common variable not $event.

---

I want to run the event on the other buttons.

I use `$event`, but I can not call function immediately.

.html

```
<p-fileUpload (onSelect)="runSelect($event)"
    accept="image/*" #imageUpload></p-fileUpload>

<button (click)="callImageSelect()" #button2></button>
```

When button2 is pressed, I want to run (onSelect) event on #imageUpload.

(onSelect) have a parameter. (event.files: List of selected files)

If press button1 to run ,

and I want to put the default value in $event.

So the way I found is to use `viewChild`.

.ts

```
@ViewChild('imageUpload') imageUpload;

...
callImageSelect() {
    this.imageUpload.**onSelect()**;   // In this section, call (onSelect).
}

runSelect(event) {
     event.files.push(defalut);
     // Here I put the default value for event.
}
```

Is there a good way?

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Why not `(click)="runSelect($event)"` ? Also sometimes, too much simplification is bad, consider giving a serious use-case.

Comment: Even if you achieve that, the `onSelect` event is not catching any text you selected in the first button. I've made a stackblitz when you can click the second button and it fires the click on the first, but is that what you need?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I have supplemented the question. Thank you.

Comment: @trichetriche I have supplemented the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to trigger event `onSelect`. The point to be noted here is `onSelect` is not a `function` but `event`. You should not call the `event` instead call the `function` which actually triggers it.

Since you are using `onSelect` which is custom event so you must be using some `Directive` for the same. So what you should do is, access the Directive inside the component and call the function which triggers the event (EventEmitter);

#### Sue-do code

```
@Directive(selector="my-directive")
public class MyDirective {

 value : string;

 onSelect = new EventEmitter();

 public selectionMade(){
      this.onSelect.emit(value);
 }

}
```

#### Component html

```
<button (onSelect)="runSelect($event)" myDirective #myDirective="myDirective"></button>

<button (click)="clickTest()" #button2></button>
```

#### Component ts

```
@ViewChild('myDirective') myDirective : MyDirective;

...
clickTest() {
    this.myDirective.selectionMade();   // In this section, call (onSelect).
}
```